Django content type showing data in `app_label: model` format in the admin dashboard
I have recently updated my application Django version from 2.2.24 to 5.0.3 after upgrading the Django I have now started getting the content_type data in this format `app_label: model` in my Django dashboard, before the update in Django admin the content_type data was shown in this format `model`.
This is the ContentType model defination, and it is imported from `django.contrib.contenttypes.models`
    class ContentTypeManager(BaseManager[ContentType]):
        def get_by_natural_key(self, app_label: str, model: str) -> ContentType: ...
        def get_for_model(
            self, model: type[Model] | Model, for_concrete_model: bool = ...
        ) -> ContentType: ...
        def get_for_models(
            self, *models: Any, for_concrete_models: bool = ...
        ) -> dict[type[Model], ContentType]: ...
        def get_for_id(self, id: int) -> ContentType: ...
        def clear_cache(self) -> None: ...

    class ContentType(models.Model):
        id: int
        app_label: models.CharField[Any] = ...
        model: models.CharField[Any] = ...
        objects: ClassVar[ContentTypeManager] = ...
        permission_set: Manager[Permission]
        @property
        def name(self) -> str: ...
        def model_class(self) -> type[Model] | None: ...
        def get_object_for_this_type(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Model: ...
        def get_all_objects_for_this_type(self, **kwargs: Any) -> QuerySet[Any]: ...
        def natural_key(self) -> tuple[str, str]: ...

**As per this change my custom build functions are now breaking.
Before it used to be like this
And after the update(the data is a bit different but the format is changed)
This is the admin code which I am using to show the data in the admin dashboard
    class ProjectTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
        experience = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'experience-selection'}),
        queryset=ContentType.objects.filter(app_label__in=app_label, model__in=models_)
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectTask
        fields = '__all__'

This is the ProjectTask model which uses ContentType model
    class ProjectTask(models.Model):
        project = models.ForeignKey('mentortogether.Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tasks')
        experience = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        item_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        item = GenericForeignKey('experience', 'item_id')
        role = models.CharField(choices=MtUserRoles.CHOICES, max_length=10, default=MtUserRoles.BOTH)

        class Meta:
            unique_together = ("project", "experie`your text`nce", "item_id")

        objects = ProjectTaskManager()

        def __str__(self):
            return "{}-{}".format(self.experience, self.item)

And I haven't updated the code realted to the ProjectTask and ProjectTask
How can I resolve this, as I have used content type at multiple places.?

"my custom build functions are now breaking" what exactly is it that is breaking? Please provide a proper [mre], only thing that seems to be changed is the string representation of the content types model.

So exactly what custom built function is breaking?

You could strictly fix this by monkey patching. So in an AppConfig set:
# some_app_name/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class SomeAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        ContentType.__str__ = __str__
But this is likely not a good idea. It might be better not to assume anything of the format of the result of a str(…) call. You can use .name attribute [Django-doc] in your custom build functions.
